# Java library for Social networking Application

Tags: java, libraries

Is there a Java library that provides  functionality for developing social network applications such as add friend, find nearest neighbors, send message etc. I know this is too much to ask for but just wanted to know if such library really exists or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very broad functionality. Here are some related projects:

- [OpenSocial Java client](https://code.google.com/p/opensocial-java-client/) - it implements the OpenSocial protocol
- [Spring-social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) allows integration with popular social networks
- [Apache Shindig](http://shindig.apache.org/) an open-social based platform.

Comment: It's not Java but Diaspora might be worth a look, too.

Comment: Be advised all of these projects are dead now

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add support for existing social network applications than I think all of the Bozho's solution would be ok for socializing your applications. For distance based calculations (geocoding) you will have to use separate mechanism and librabry google and yahoo both have an excellent api for that though these differ in terms of their usage restrictions so its good to you research before deciding one, Yahoo also supplies a promising feature YQL which is also useful in some cases.... Which one of them is better depends on your requirements... see following questions [finding latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582614/how-to-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-point-from-a-given-point-given-the-d), [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778992/how-to-find-distance-between-two-addresses-java-server-side) and [finding distance between two zipCodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426710/how-to-find-the-distance-between-two-zipcodes-using-java-code)

If you want to create your own social networking site as then I think you will have to start by ur own... However It would be a nice idea to integrate that site with existing popular social networks using OAuth or open ID....

Answer (score 3):

@Bozho's answer is valid, all those libraries integrate with a set of Social services.

This question really depends on the extent of integration you want. I've worked on a couple of large scale Social aggregators and I've found that such a silver bullet just doesn't exist.  I've found the best results in my experience by using small lightweight libraries that do one thing well.

For example, say I wanted to integrate with Twitter, Facebook, and Google Talk. I might use Scribe for my authentication code, Jackson for parsing JSON API responses to my business objects and Smack for doing my XMPP work.

There are certainly pros and cons for both methods; the major benefits I've found of avoiding massive libraries are:

- Flexibility. For example your business objects only contain the information you care about.
- Testability. You can compose your components in such a way that tests are easy to write around them.
- Robust. You are not constrained by a 3rd parties implementation of typically volatile 3rd party APIs.
- Less code. Using a collection of small, proven libraries will result in less of a footprint: less code to manage = less that can go wrong.